# What does "@" do in an angular directive?

Tags: angularjs

Building an angular directive, and can't find anywhere what the "@" means..

```
.directive('mydirective', function() 
{
   return {
      scope: {
         test: "@"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that this property will have the value indicated in the attribute.

In your case:

```
<mydirective test="hello">
</mydirective>
```

The value of `scope.test` of that instance of the directive will "hello".

```
.directive('mydirective', function() 
{
   return {
      scope: {
         test: "@"
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
          // scope.test == "hello"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object) say it means.

> @ or @attr - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM
>   attribute. The result is always a string since DOM attributes are
>   strings. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is
>   assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: { localName:'@myAttr' },
>   then widget scope property localName will reflect the interpolated
>   value of hello {{name}}. As the name attribute changes so will the
>   localName property on the widget scope. The name is read from the
>   parent scope (not component scope).

So it's similar to the `=` but instead of binding to a value from a different scope it is binding to the attribute value in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

In angular we can bind the values by three ways to the directive.

1.) =

2.) &

3.) @

"=" is used for 2 way binding. I change in controller. reflects in directive and reverse.

"&" is used for expressions. Should be used for passing the functions.

"@" Is used for one way bind. This is received as a string. But anyhow you can parse to get the object. So its good to send one way binded data. (Changes done in directive doesn't reflect back in controller)

Other way to send the data is through attributes. You can receive it through "attr" argument in link function.